# defaults delete domain is not working

Tags: macos, command-line, defaults

I'm trying to clear out the defaults for an app I'm working on.

```
defaults read com.mycompany.Foo
```

That prints a bunch of stuff.

```
defaults delete com.mycompany.Foo
```

Silent.

```
defaults read com.mycompany.Foo
```

It's all still there. Why?

```
defaults delete com.mycompany.Foo specificKey
```

This appears to work. But I don't want to go through key by key. I'd like to delete the entire domain.

Answer (score 0):

Find the `*.plist` that corresponds to the `defaults` settings for the `domain`.

```sh
### user settings search
find ~/Library -name "com.mycompany.AppName.plist" -print
find $XCODE_DERIVED_DATA -name "com.mycompany.AppName.plist" -print

### system search... likely a broader search than needed
sudo find / -name "com.mycompany.AppName.plist" -print
```

Removes all default information for `domain`:

```sh
defaults delete com.mycompany.AppName
```

The `defaults delete com.mycompany.AppName` commands clears the contents of the XML `.plist` associated with the domain.

Completely remove the `domain` from `defaults`:

```sh
### cautiously delete file manually or with `rm`
rm /PATH/TO/com.mycompany.AppName.plist
```

*Note: If the "com.mycompany.AppName" application or service is running, then do not be surprised when `defaults read com.mycompany.AppName` has regenerated the `*.plist` and still returns values. Also, a "com.mycompany.AppName" executable relaunch can itself recreate the preference defaults `*.plist` again.*